# Microsoft Access query using the alternative of ROW_NUMBER for duplicate date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Obviously there are a bunch of questions about `ROW_NUMBER` in MS Access and the usual response is that it does not exist but instead to use a COUNT(*) to create something similar. Unfortunately, doing so does not give me the results that I need.

My data looks like:

```
employee_id -------start_time ------- start_date
000670 -----------------12:30 ------------ 2019/03/28
000670 -----------------11:22 ------------ 2019/03/30
000676 -----------------13:00 ------------ 2019/03/28
000676 -----------------11:30 ------------ 2019/03/29
000676 -----------------14:00 ------------ 2019/03/29
000676 -----------------11:20 ------------ 2019/03/30
000676 -----------------14:00 ------------ 2019/03/30
000676 -----------------11:00 ------------ 2019/03/31
000677 -----------------11:20 ------------ 2019/03/28
000677 -----------------12:20 ------------ 2019/03/29
000678 -----------------12:00 ------------ 2019/03/29
```

Using the `COUNT(*)` I get:

```
employee_id -------- start_date ------- seq
000670  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000670  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 2
000676  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000676  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 3
000676  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 3
000676  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 5
000676  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 5
000676  ------------ 2019/03/31 ------- 6
000677  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000677  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 2
000678  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 1
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT tbl.employee_id
     , tbl.start_date
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM tbl AS tbl2 
          WHERE tbl2.employee_id = tbl.employee_id 
            AND tbl2.start_date <= tbl.start_date ) AS seq
  FROM tbl
ORDER BY tbl.employee_id, tbl.start_date
```

What I am trying to get at is a unique count over employee_id and start_date so that my query output looks like:

```
employee_id -------- start_date ------- seq
000670  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000670  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 2
000676  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000676  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 2
000676  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 3
000676  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 4
000676  ------------ 2019/03/30 ------- 5
000676  ------------ 2019/03/31 ------- 6
000677  ------------ 2019/03/28 ------- 1
000677  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 2
000678  ------------ 2019/03/29 ------- 1
```

Comment: I think you are going to need to involve a third column which can break the ties.  Or, switch to a database which supports `ROW_NUMBER`, if you forsee a long term need for this type of query.

Comment: I have added a (start_time) column here. I need to do the query in MSAccess. Is there have any way to solve the problem?

Comment: If every timestamp be unique, then your current query should already be working.

Comment: Here is the problem. In this case, the timestamp is not unique. That's why when any duplicate date insert in the start_date column, I get the duplicate seq number.  but I need the seq number incremental though it gets duplicate timestamp.

Comment: An alternative to query calculation is to use report Sorting & Grouping features and RunningSum property of textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

FOR SQL

```
SELECT 
    tbl.employee_id, tbl.start_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id)As Row_Num 
FROM tbl
```

FOR MS ACCESS

```
SELECT tbl.employee_id
     , tbl.start_date
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM tbl AS tbl2 
          WHERE tbl2.employee_id = tbl.employee_id 
         AND  tbl2.start_date+tbl2.start_time < tbl.start_date+tbl.start_time
         )+1 AS seq
  FROM tbl
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() function does not support in ms-access query. Can you prefer me another way without using row_number() function?